# WiFi connection is up but doesn't work: code or android bug?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I wrote an app that use Alarm manager to execute a service (that hold a wakelock to perform the entire execution) every minutes to upload data on net, and it works perfect....sometimes.

Infact using Logcat (on phone) i saw that sometimes the WiFi connection doesn't work. The icon on the status bar it's ok, and i had set "never" for wifi standby.

Sometimes the app is running ok for more than 20 hours, some other times just 40 minutes and then wifi seems to be down (but there is still icon and configuration rigth set).

Doing a last test i tried to open the browser and it doesn't work too! Torestart the upload i need to disable and enable wifi...So i think that the problem is in android.

My device is Samsung Galaxy ACE with Android 2.2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved only doing a disable and enable connection bettween the operation.

```
//disable connection
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,1);
// Post an intent to reload
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
intent1.putExtra("state", 1);
sendBroadcast(intent1);
//connection disabled


//enable connection
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,0);
// Post an intent to reload
Intent intent4 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
intent4.putExtra("state", 0);
sendBroadcast(intent4);
//Connection enabled
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, the question is too broad to answer. Perhaps you can post the code that you mention?

Also, for further debugging,

- did you try over a different wifi network?
- does the wi-fi work if you never start your app?

**Update:**

Sounds like it could be a DNS issue on your network. When the wi-fi is "down", can you check if DNS resolution works on other devices in the same network (that use the same DNS server)?

Comment: Thanx! I can't post the code because is too long. The neccesary to understand is wrote in the question (AlarmManager, WakeLock and Service).

Comment: I think that the problem is inside android! No i can't try different net, i don't know second answer...